# Error Trying to Remotely Manage Hyper-V 2012 from Windows 8 Pro Without a Domain

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, windows-8, hyper-v-server-2012

I took sometime this long holiday weekend to install Hyper-V Server 2012 and Windows 8 Pro (on separate hardware, same LAN) to hopefully get a little more familiar with it. From the WIN8 client I am unable to connect to any VMs using the Virtual Machine Connection or the Hyper-V manager. I get the the following error:

`You do not have the required permission to complete this task.`

Basically, here are the steps I followed on the HYPERV server:

- Installed Hyper-V Server 2012 and ran all Windows Updates
- Disabled the firewall: `Get-NetFirewallProfile | Set-NetFirewallProfile –Enabled False`
- Added a local account `Goyuix` on HYPERV server
- Ran [hvremote.wsf](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-Remote-Management-26d127c6): `cscript hvremote.wsf /add:HYPERV\Goyuix`

And the WIN8 client:

- Installed Windows 8 Pro
- Disabled the firewall: `Get-NetFirewallProfile | Set-NetFirewallProfile –Enabled False`
- Added a local account `Goyuix` on WIN8 client
- Ran [hvremote.wsf](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-Remote-Management-26d127c6): `cscript hvremote.wsf /anondcom:grant`

When I run the `cscript hvremote.wsf /show /target:HYPERV` command from the WIN8 client, I get the following message as a failure:

`Cannot connect to root\cimv2 on HYPERV`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a HOSTS file to resolve the server name from the client, you could try making sure to use the server name only and not FQDN, per this:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-Remote-Management-26d127c6/view/Discussions#content

Also, check the Windows Security event log to see if there are any additional details about authentication.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had tried with IP address and it was definitely not happy with that. After rebooting the HYPERV server and connecting by host name things appear to be working. Thanks!